# Issues running Ionic on Macbook

Tags: ionic-framework, terminal, download

I have been having issues running ionic on my MacBook. I have `npm` and node downloaded yet my system still doesn't seem to allow me to get Ionic to run. I have tried running it with the sudo command too.

When I run the command `npm install -g ionic` I get:

```
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/Janelle/.npm/_logs/2022-03-27T18_13_54_411Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: This is covered in the manual: https://ionicframework.com/docs/developing/tips#resolving-permission-errors

Comment: you should installed NVM first and then install nodejs via NVM. check this: https://learn2torials.com/a/how-to-install-nvm 
Using NVM will remove all permission related issues and you can easily use anything via npm install

Answer (score -1):

looks like ionic was not installed correctly initially, you can always try and remove ionic and re-install. You should not have to run it with `sudo`

Comment: The error is occurring while trying to install ioinic. It is [the first command in the install guide](https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/cli) that is failing. They can't remove and reinstall it because they haven't managed to install it in the first place.

Comment: Quentin -  you don't know that they cant uninstall it, they in fact said that they tried to install it and so it is quite possible there were errors in the initial installation of ionic when they used `sudo` which she stated... so your assumption that it isn't partially installed or some other error occurred during the initial install is an assumption... we are all just trying to help out here